# Cascaded SwiftUI views inside UIKIT view

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have this working fine:-
UIKIT view -> SwiftUI view (ListContainerView)
///

```
    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ListContainerView(dismissAction: bridge))
    let swiftuiView = vc.view!
    bridge.closeAction = { [weak vc] in
        vc?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In ListContainerView, I have a button which calls another SwiftUI view...

```
        Button {
            AddContainerView()
        } label: {
            Label("", systemImage: "plus.circle")
        }
```

But, it is not working...
Is it possible to have cascaded SwiftUI views inside UIKIT view?
UIKIT view -> SwiftUI View #1 -> SwiftUI View #2